# ActiveForm yii2 on validation form error

Tags: php, view, yii2, active-form

I have a view:

```
<?= $form->field($registration, 'username',
            ['template' => '<div class="uk-form-row">
                                <label for="register_username">{label}</label>
                                {input}{error}
                                </div>'])
            ->textInput(['class' => 'md-input']) ?>
```

And I want it to add new class to `textInput` after the error was triggered.
In the model there's some rules for this input:

```
['username', 'string', 'min' => 2, 'max' => 255, 'message' => 'Can not be blank'],
['username','required']
```

And for example if I type 1 symbols that will trigger an error that will say `Can not be blank`. But also I want to add `md-input-danger` class **on this input**. Is there's a proper way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should apply some options to your Form:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'layout' => 'horizontal',
    'fieldConfig' => [
        'horizontalCssClasses' => [
            'error' => 'md-input-danger'
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Comment: It doesn't add or change input classes. Is it supposed to? Can you provide some information about `'layout' => 'horizontal'`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use yii\web\ActiveField look at:

[yii-widgets-activefield.html#$errorOptions-detail](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#$errorOptions-detail)

Code should be like:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'fieldConfig' => [
        'errorOptions' => ['class' => 'md-input-danger']
    ],
]);
```

P.S. Hutsi`s code uses yii\bootstrap\ActiveField

Comment: According to documentation this will change generated error tag. Not the input. "_The default options for the error tags._"

Comment: I didn`t try that,but maybe you can change 'selectors' property of fieldConfig to point to your input? And then errorOptions will change directly class of input.